# Set a default text value for HTML table via CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a document with HTML that will hold results from a lengthy survey. All questions on the survey are not required, and more often than not, no response is recorded for numerous fields.

Here is an example of my  HTML code;

```
<p id="h1"> Section 1 - Introduction </p>
<p> </p>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th> 
        <div> 
        First Name 
        </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
        <div> 
        ${R.Contact First Name}
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p></p>
<table id="t1">
  <tr>
    <th> 
        <div> 
        Last Name 
        </div>
    </th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td> 
        <div> 
        $(R.Contact Last Name}
        </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And my supporting CSS:

```
<style>
table#t1 th 
{
    background-color: #EFF1F4;
    text-align: left;
    border: 1px solid #EFF1F4;
}

table#t1 td
{
 background-color: white;
    text-align: left;
    border: 2px solid #EFF1F4;
}

table#t1
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 35px;
}

p#h2
{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: italic;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 35px;
}

p#h1
{
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 25px 0px 0px 35px;
}

p#b1
{
    page-break-after:always;
}
div
{
    min-height: 15px;
    font-size: 11px;
}
</style>
```

The program I'm using will fill the parameter values (${R.Contact First Name}) if there is a value inputted by the user. If there is no user inputted value, this section will currently show up blank.

What I'd like to do is set the `<tr>` to a default value of 'No response' with a lighter text color, and italicized, such that if there is a response, it pulls it normally, but if there is no response, this differently formatted 'no response' text pulls in.

**The number of characters is a constraint. The document must not exceed 100,000 characters, so ideally the solution would be within the CSS of the code, and would be referenced in each table by an ID, rather than setting a text string value at the beginning of each table.

Is this possible or am I over-reaching the functionality of HTML?

Comment: It's possible to set a default value for `<tr>` fields with JavaScript, but not with CSS. Do you have access to JavaScript?

Comment: Sounds like this should be a `form` with `inputs` and then you can use the `placeholder` attribute for that default text.

Comment: @MichaelCoker  I looked into the placeholder functionality, but again it appeared that you would have to set a placeholder at the beginning of each table, rather than in CSS, correct me if im wrong?

Comment: @dibiasem yeah, the `placeholder` would be an attribute on an `input` tag, so it would be in the HTML.

Comment: @MichaelCoker I think this would work for if the form had user input, however the way I am exporting this document will be strictly read-only.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `:empty` psuedoselector:

CSS

```
p:empty {
  position: relative;
}
p:empty:before {
  color: #808080;
  content: "This is CSS-generated.";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}
```

HTML

```
<p>
  This has some content.
</p>
<p></p>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yak613/2occ8j38/

However, you need to make sure that there is no white space inside the element, or else the selector will not find it. The CSS4 `:blank` selector is currently not supported by any browsers, but if it does work out, it will work even with white space. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/b/blank/

Comment: Interesting, but I don't think my `<div>` tags would be classified as empty in any instance, because technically upon passing into the HTML they are assigned an initial text value (that is later replaced once the application prints the document).

Comment: How are you processing this? If it's being done server-side, then the CSS will only get empty `div`s to style.

Comment: The HTML and CSS I've created will act as a 'shell' for the input for a Survey executed in a CRM system. The CRM holds the values like First Name in fields under the syntax ${R.First Name}, as an example. I'll add an image of what is currently outputted if there is a field value and is not a field value.

Comment: So use jQuery to style it dynamically after the field shows up as empty.